# How to append the letters ULL to a number you don't already know in C

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define APPEND(x, y) x ## y
#define ULL(x) APPEND(x, ull)

int main (void) 
{
    unsigned long long int a = ULL(12345678901234567890);
    printf("val: 0x%llx\n", a);
    return 0; 
}
```

It returns the hex value of a registry qword 12345678901234567890.

How do I change this as it could be any number rather than a specific one.

---

[Update from OP's deleted "answer"]

Do I change

```
unsigned long long int a = ULL(12345678901234567890);
```

to

```
unsigned long long int a = (unsigned long long)
```

where x will = 12345678901234567890

Sorry for sounding stupid on here.... but the value of x could be anything.

Comment: `ULL` is for specifying the type of an integer *literal* (a constant in your source code) as `unsigned long long`. If the value isn't constant, I have no idea what you're trying to do here.

Comment: This seems like a XY problem. Does your function reading from the registry return a 32-bit number?

Answer (score 3):

As @Felix Palmen said, `ULL` is for specifying of an integral literal.

---

Let's say if the function return that big number, you would do

```
unsigned long long int a = (unsigned long long) function_which_return_big_number();
```

But to allow this function return that big number, it already has to be `unsigned long long`.

---

Last usecase could be that these large numbers could be strings, then you would use [strtoull](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoull/).

Comment: Thanks to both of you, please remember I'm new to C, so how do I change the above posted code?   

Do I change unsigned long long int a = ULL(12345678901234567890); to unsigned long long int a = (unsigned long long)

where x will = 12345678901234567890

Sorry for sounding stupid on here.... but the value of x could be anything.

Thanks again - appreciated!

Comment: Yes just change it to `unsigned long long int a = (unsigned long long)(x);` Everyone was beginner once :-)